# Angular 2: ng-container in SVG

Tags: angular, svg

I have a Component with a template that consists of SVG elements.
Those elements should be conditionally be rendered with **ngIf*. But because *ng-container* is not a valid SVG element, it can't be used. So I used the SVG group element (g). The advantage of *ng-container* is that it does not appear in the DOM. But *g*-elements do appear in the DOM and so the DOM gets polluted. 
Is there a work-around?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use `<svg:svg></svg>` instead of `<svg></svg>`.